# I try jquery tutorial, but it does not give the expected output

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

this program will pop-up a alert message when user click on the text showed, then make the text to uppercase.

```
<script src="jquery-min.js"></script>
<script>
   //run once the page is loaded
   jquery(document).ready(function ($) {
       //Attach a click event to the span element
       $('#test_span').click(function () {
          //Read the elemnt's current value
          var elemnt_text = $('#test_span').html();
          //display the curretn value of this span
          alert(element_text);
          //convert the value to upper case
          element_text = element_text.toUpperCase();
          //change the span to this new value
          $('#test_span').html(element_text);
       });
  });
</script>
</head>
<span id='test_span'>Testing jQuery</span>
```

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this,  **elemnt_text** spelling  not correct. use **element_text**

To get text contents  of the element, Use **[.text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/)** instead of `.html()`

```
var element_text = $('#test_span').text();
```

instead of

```
 var elemnt_text = $('#test_span').html();
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/rk72eu8m/

[**Difference between jQuery text() and html() functions**](http://www.jquerybyexample.net/2011/02/difference-between-jquery-text-and-html.html)

Comment: thank you so much. But May I know why use .text() instead of .html(). I read from the jquery api doc, the different is .html() not available fro XML file but .text(). Is there other reasons?

Comment: @user3809706 `.html()` Processes the string as HTML whereas `.text()` Processes the content as text.

Answer (score 0):

You had spelling mistake.Try this

```
 <script src="jquery-min.js"></script>
    <script>
        //run once the page is loaded
        $(document).ready(function () {
            //Attach a click event to the span element
            $('#test_span').click(function () {

                //Read the elemnt's current value

                var element_text = $('#test_span').html();

                //display the curretn value of this span
                alert(element_text);

                //convert the value to upper case
                element_text = element_text.toUpperCase();

                //change the span to this new value
                $('#test_span').html(element_text);
            });
        });
</script>
    </head>

        <span id='test_span'>Testing jQuery</span>
```

hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Typo:

`var elemnt_text = $('#test_span').html();`

your variable is misspelled. It should be `element_text`.

It should work with that correction.

Answer (score 0):

change your codes to this <kbd>[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/abbasmhd/xgc8h4z5/)</kbd>

```
var elemnt = $('#test_span');

//Attach a click event to the span element
elemnt.click(function () {

    //Read the elemnt's current value
    var element_text = elemnt.text();

    //display the curretn value of this span
    alert(element_text);

    //convert the value to upper case
    element_text = element_text.toUpperCase();

    //change the span to this new value
    $('#test_span').html(element_text);
});
```